# How can I auto-format Rmd on save?

Tags: r, coding-style, r-markdown

In python it's possible to use Black to auto format code on save in multiple editors. My problem: I would like to use a similar approach for R, but don't know how.

I'm aware of the 'auto format' function in RStudio, but would like to use a linter/formatter in SublimeText.

Any solution should auto format R code inside Rmd and/or the markdown itself, ideally on file save.

What would be some good packages to use for this, and ways of configuring them for friction-free editing? Does such a solution already exist?

Comment: If you're using RStudio, you can use `CTRL+SHIFT+A` to reformat code. For more advanced formatting, there's the [`styler` package](http://styler.r-lib.org/index.html) and add-in.

Comment: I don't normally vote-to-close this soon after a question is posted, but this is well within the realm of *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"* on the list of [off-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @r2evans the rationale for that rule is that such questions may "tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". This isn't the case here though, so why close it? Its hard to google this stuff because searching for the letter R doesn't work well, and the packages tend to have cute names. I could artificially reformulate my question as an "I want this... I did this... How can I solve" but that's just not helpful...

Comment: I disagree that this will not drive opinionated answers. *"This tool defaults to github markdown layout, which I prefer."*. But perhaps *"that other tool uses black-for-r so is obviously superior"* (I do not know of an actual "black-for-r"). You want a **recommendation**, which is by definition *"a suggestion or proposal as to the best course of action"* -- and "best" is subjective. (Unless you know of an objective measure of code linters.) @bjw, I don't consider this an evil question, and perhaps SoftwareRecs would be a better SE site. (Have you tried Jason's mention of `styler`? Perhaps ...)

Comment: @r2evans This isn't the same as just asking for a software recommendation - it's asking for knowledge of how a particular task (auto format on save) could be achieved.  SoftwareRecs doesn't have the expertise of people viewing on a specialist topic like this. Overly restrictive moderation is ruining sites like SO. There are many answers on this site now locked for this reason which provide very useful context/suggestions for good practice written by experts. It would be interesting to see engagement stats for articles like this... my hunch is that they do provide real value to users.

Comment: I cannot argue much about SWRecs: it is under-frequented, and as such appears to be not solving this type of question/issue very well. I don't wholly agree with your statement about SO moderation (I am not a moderator), though I do agree that some steps moderators take seem unnecessary; and as you know sites like this are prone to bullying, nasty comments, not-well-communicated sarcasm, etc (I'm guilty at times). I believe SE *staff* is actively/intentionally trying to reverse this trend.

Comment: While I still think [styler](http://styler.r-lib.org/index.html) likely addresses your initial question, I realize your discussion now is about a proper forum for non-traditional requests like this. I don't have an answer, sorry. I'd suggest you take it to Meta, but that can at times seem even more "hostile" than SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can reformat code in RStudio "Code" -> "Reformat Code". However, I don't really like to have this done automatically and I don't particularly like some of the reformatting RStudio does.

For code style there is an excellent package which will notify you of any problems and brings you to the position in the file (if you use RStudio):

```
#install.packages("lintr")
lintr::lint("/path/to/file/Report.Rmd")
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I should have mentioned that I'd ideally like a solution that format on save, and worked cross-editor (especially in SublimeText).